# Is there a way to log apache's request time in milliseconds?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there an equivalent to %D or %T which shows the total request time in milliseconds instead of microseconds or seconds?

The rest of our systems (DB and app servers) usually log request times in milliseconds. Is there a way to log Apache's request time in milliseconds so that all of our servers log using the same unit of time?

EDIT: I want to know the total number of milliseconds that a request takes. I can see the documentation for setting the timestamp - which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html tells you how.

Comment: @jenny - I don't see anything in that documentation that tells me how to do what I asked. But I can see how you are confused because "time" is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, divide by 1000.

Comment: Michael - how do I divide %D by 1000 in the log file? I didn't realize it was possible to do math expressions.

Comment: You do it with your log analysis tools after the logs are written.  If you can't do that, then you write a script to convert the logs before sending your analysis tools on them.  If neither of those are acceptable, you're going to have to write a patch for apache (or hire someone to write one) or give up.

Comment: @yoonix - thanks for the comment. I was hoping someone knew of a workaround to log milliseconds directly.

Comment: %{ms}T is available in 2.2.30 and later, see [httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html)

Comment: It's beyond me how this question could be deemed off-topic. From https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic: "Your question is on-topic if it is about: a) managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks (check) b) tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these (check) c) deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms (check).
On the other hand, this question does not match ANY of the reasons mentioned for marking a question off-topic.
If questions are closed without valid reasons people will stop asking..

Comment: I don't understand it either. It is a rather trivial question or irrelevant (by now) since it's all in the docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html But I don't see why it should be off topic.

Answer (score 9):

You can. Take a look at the docs here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

```
%{ms}T
```

provides request duration in ms, and is available in 2.2.30 and later,

```
%{%d/%b/%Y:%T}t-%{msec_frac}
```

is the best you can do before 2.2.30

Comment: That only tells me the timestamp in milliseconds, but I am looking for the measurement of the amount of time the request took.

Comment: You can't time requests as a log output as far as I know. What you may need to do is handle that in your application code, and log that from your app separately.

Comment: I'm already using %D to time the requests in microseconds so it is definitely possible. You can also use %T for time in seconds. The only thing I can't find is a way to log in milliseconds.

Comment: @nimblegorilla the problem with %D and %T is they tell you how long it took to send data to the client, not how long the page took to build.

Comment: you can use `%{us}T` to get the request duration in milliseconds, taken from apache mod log config documentation for `%{UNIT}T`:

The time taken to serve the request, in a time unit given by UNIT. Valid units are ms for milliseconds, us for microseconds, and s for seconds. Using s gives the same result as %T without any format; using us gives the same result as %D. Combining %T with a unit is available in 2.2.30 and later.

Comment: @DesertEagle you meant %{ms}T. but otherwise, good eye!

Comment: Is there any way to match nginx format, which is "time in seconds with a milliseconds resolution"? Something like 0.021.

Comment: According to the docs: "Combining %T with a unit is available in 2.4.13 and later." Not 2.2.30 as you wrote. I am using 2.4.6 and it does not work for me. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html